# Why did Messi pass this penalty kick?

Tags: football, penalty-shot

Why didn't Messi kick at the goal and passed instead? Perhaps I have not seen a scene like this before and after it. Was there a particular reason?

In [17 Impossible Things Only Messi Can Do - With Commentaries](https://youtu.be/tF2_bIpqFYg?t=42), he was at a penalty kick.

[image]

But he did not kick towards the net, rather rolled the ball right, and Suárez scored a goal.

[image]

Comment: Johan Cruyff did it first. And only Messi knows *why* he passed it.

Comment: Pires and Henry tried to do same with Arsenal but missed [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjX7okJH-lQ]